How to set a CheckboxGridItem to require one answer per column?
I'm using an app script to create a Google form, from the data in a spreadsheet. So far, it's been working fine!
I have one question that is a grid. I want the question to be unskippable (or for it to require one answer for each column), but I don't want to require an answer for each row. I have more rows than columns, and It would be bad for the UX to transpose the rows and columns.
Let's use the example from the documentation:
// Add a checkbox grid item to a form and require one response per column.
var checkboxGridItem = form.addCheckboxGridItem();
checkboxGridItem.setTitle('Where did you celebrate New Years?')
  .setRows(['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London'])
  .setColumns(['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017']);
var checkboxGridValidation = FormApp.createCheckboxGridValidation()
  .setHelpText(“Select one item per column.”)
  .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()
  .build();
checkboxGridItem.setValidation(checkboxGridValidation);

I used the .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn() data validation.
What it does is it makes it impossible for the user to check more than one item in each column (good). But the question itself is not required, so a few of my users have skipped it.
Recently I tried the setRequired() method. The code would look like this:
// Add a checkbox grid item to a form and require one response per column.
var checkboxGridItem = form.addCheckboxGridItem();
checkboxGridItem.setTitle('Where did you celebrate New Years?')
  .setRows(['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London'])
  .setColumns(['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'])
  .setRequired(true);  //<<< here is the part I added
var checkboxGridValidation = FormApp.createCheckboxGridValidation()
  .setHelpText(“Select one item per column.”)
  .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()
  .build();
checkboxGridItem.setValidation(checkboxGridValidation);

What it does is, It makes the question require one answer for each row! It makes it impossible for the user to answer that question, since we have the limit of only one response per column, and I have more rows than columns.
The google form is constantly giving error messages like these:

"Não selecione mais de uma resposta por coluna" = "Do not select more than one answer per column"
"Esta pergunta exige pelo menos uma resposta por linha" = "This question requires at least one answer per line"

How can I create a grid question that is required (the question itself is required, not a requirement of one answer for each line), and simultaneously that only allows one answer per column?

Based on what you have shared, you can consider each row of the question as a sub question if you are requiring this part to be answered then you are on the right track, and setRequired(true) is what you need. You can remove this part .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn() is the one you need to remove. If you need 1 answer per row only then you need a different type of question. You will need a gridItem.

.setRequired(true);  //<<< here is the part I added You can't add a feature that doesn't exist. In the context of a "CheckBoxGridItem", required has a different meaning than other items. In this context it means "require one answer for each row". I agree with @Babanana. You need to consider a different type of question.

You may request this feature to Google by Clicking Help>Send Feedback.
